# Static header + menu, scrollable body

Tags: css, layout, header, menu

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
+--------screen-----------------------+
|       ______________________      |*|
|       |_static_header______|      |*|
|       |             |      |      |*|
|       | content     |menu  |      |*|
|       | scrollable  |static|      |*|
|       |             |      |      |*|
|       |             |      |      |*|
|       |             |      |      |*|
+-------------------------------------+
```

The content is of variable height, and the content scrollbar must be show in the page body (and not on it's on area).
I managed to get the basic idea, but I'm having trouble to getting the content div in it's correct position when the scrollbar shows, and even if I set to always show the scrollbars, I can't use a fixed width because they differ from browser to browser.

```
<div style="position:absolute; background-color:Transparent; left:0px; right:0px; height:100px; z-index:2;">
    <div style="background-color:Silver; width:1000px; height:100px; margin:0 auto;">
        Header
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Fixed div acting as the body "page" so the scrollbar shows as the page's -->
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; overflow-y:auto; padding-top:100px; z-index:1;">
    <div style="position:relative; width:800px; height:100%; margin:0 auto; padding-right:200px;">
        <div style="background-color:Orange; width:100%; height:900px;">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute; left:50%; right:0px; padding-top:100px; z-index:0;">
    <div style="width:500px; float:left;">
        <div style="background-color:Green; float:right; width:200px; ">
            Menu
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

In code above the content is off by the scrollbar width, how can I get it right with the rest of the page (ie. calculating it's position without considering the scrollbar width, even if it has one)?

Comment: +1 ascii graphic. And it always nice to see good formatted question from a new user on SO.

Comment: Is this to be fixed width or should the header span the whole viewport?

Comment: The whole "body" (header, content+menu below) are to be on a fixed width. I had problems before with really large wide monitors when I didn't set a fixed width...

Comment: Understanding your HTML was quite difficult, can I suggest that in future you add appropriate class names/IDs and use a stylesheet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly this will be a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7pJS8/

Comment: Suppose the static header section wasn't a constant height, but varying according to the situation? Is there still a css-only way to get the content below it to scroll, rather than the whole window?

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
body {
    padding: 0px;
}
.container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}

#header {
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#header .container {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
}

#content {
    background: green;
    height: 1500px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#content .inner {
    margin-right: 200px;
}

#sidebar {
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#sidebar .inner {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
}
</style>

<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
        header
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">
            sidebar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/zWERN/

Answer (score 1):

Setting a scroll on all of the page, might result in a disappearing header and menu - when the content is long.

What you're looking for is a subset of the [Holy Grail design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Grail_(web_design)).

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/swHKE2?p=preview)'s an implementation using the flex display:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Holy Grail</title>
    <!-- Reset browser defaults -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  </head>
  <body style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
    <div>HEADER<br/>------------
    </div>
    <!-- No need for 'flex-direction: row' because it's the default value -->
    <div style="display: flex; flex: 1">
      <div>NAV|</div>
      <div style="flex: 1; overflow: auto">
        CONTENT - START<br/>
        <script>
        for (var i=0 ; i<1000 ; ++i) {
          document.write(" Very long content!");
        }
        </script>
        <br/>CONTENT - END
      </div>
      <div>|SIDE</div>
    </div>
    <div>------------<br/>FOOTER</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is ways to do it with fixed heights and then use the overflow property on the scrollable areas. However, that's not good practice, what you should look at is using a sticky header or scrolling header (one that follows the viewing area as the user scrolls up and down) from jQuery or your JS library of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `position:fixed` solve your problem? If you set `position:fixed` to header and menu div?

Comment: Yep it does, though I vaguely remember this not being a "standard" option. Or maybe it was regarding background-position, now I'm not sure. I'm going to give it a try, thanks!